# Unity - SetActive() on GameObject dont works on child's objects

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, parent-child

I have the following line of code:

```
GameObject.Find("_obstacles").SetActive(false);
```

It serves to leave an inactive object, but the children of this object are not getting with the same status.

***My result is:***

[image]

> The objects children do not inherit the parent object state (as stated in the > documentation of Unity)!

But the obsolete method "`SetActiveRecursively()`" works for me! O.o The Very strange, no?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Took a look into Unitys Docs and found this, seems like they havent removed it yet but its not recomended to use this either.

> SetActiveRecursively has been kept in the API for 4.0 but its use is
>   not recommended and it may be removed in the future

Basically all it does it loop through the parents children and set i active/inactive.
Create a custom method just in case Unity removes the `SetActiveRecursively` completelty from thier API.

Link to [SetActiveRecursively()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DeactivatingGameObjects.html)

And last but not least, seems like Unitys created gameobject in play mode doesnt inherit that parents active state.

Comment: "And last but not least, seems like Unitys created gameobject in play mode doesnt inerheit that parents active state." That tells me a lot! My object is created dynamically!

Comment: @IgoR do you need more help? If this or another answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to accept that answer. Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [Why is voting important?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score -1):

Of course it does not impact child GameObjects

You can have an Object A, with 2 sub-objects B and C, have them configured with B Active and C Inactive.

Now you want your hierarchy active by calling `A.SetActive(true)`, that doesn't mean you want to activate C.

The question is why your sub-objects are Inactive themself? Because an inactive parent is enough.

I suggest you to keep your sub-objects Active, or to [develop your own SetActiveRecursively method looping through all Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html).